# How to filter out numbers from an inputted User Name

Tags: string, oop, if-statement, error-handling

I am trying to get the user to enter the Name (of their choice) of a building, but the name cannot include any digits from 0 to 9 that's the only restriction. If they include a digit, the program simply tells them the entry is invalid and that they must try again. My issue is I don't think I'm using the loop correctly so it still accepts invalid answers

Here is what I've written:

```
buildName = (input('Enter the building name: '))
         for char in buildName:
            if char.isdigit():
               break
            print('Invalid Entry')
            buildName = input('Re-Enter the building name: ')
            
         building.setBuildName(buildName)
```

I feel like this should be working. But, I am stuck.

To be more specific on the output validity, entries like "C-Building" should work while "123C-Building" should not

Comment: Please update your question and include which programming language you are using as tag.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is the break; because of it you are getting out of your loop so the rest of your code is not executed. To fix the problem you could make a new string that will only accepts non-digits. So your "if" would append the non-digits to the new list. By doing That you don't need to ask the user for a new entry because you filtered it form him